# Is there a way to prevent creation of anonymous (inner) classes, but allow inheritance of the class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have this class:

```
public class MainClass {
    ...
}
```

This class should be extended by another class to inherit it's attirubtes and methods.
So this should be allowed:

```
public class ChildrenClass extends MainClass {
    ...
}
```

But i don't want another developers to create inner classes (anonymous classes) from my MainClass, like this:

```
MainClass anonymousClassInstance = new MainClass(){...}
```

Is there a way to do it in java?

Comment: Probably not - can you give more info on why you want to prevent anonymous class instantiation?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? From a technical (JVM) point of view there is no difference between the two classes (except for the class *names*)

Comment: Making the method `final` in MainClass can prevent overriding if that's what you try to avoid.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Then even child can't override them.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yes that's the point, you still can make some abstract method you would like the child class to implement.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Um, no. Final and abstract are opposites, and it's a compile-time error to combine them.

Comment: Not entirely sure this will work but: If all subclasses are in the same package you could make `MainClass` package private to avoid it being extended by any class in other packages.

Comment: @André Stannek well that would do, so how do i make my MainClass package private?

Comment: use `protected`. I'll try it out myself and write an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue But more than that, you can't have an abstract method in a final class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all subclasses are in the same package you could make `MainClass` package private to avoid it being extended by any class in other packages.

```
package mainPackage;

class MainClass { // note the missing public modifier

}
```

Subclass in the same package:

```
package mainPackage;

public class SubClass extends MainClass { // this extension works

}
```

Extension in other package:

```
package externalPackage;

import mainPackage.MainClass;

public class SomeClass {

    public void foo() {
        MainClass foo = new MainClass() { 
        // doesn't work because `MainClass` is not visible
        };
    }

}
```

The problem with this is, that `MainClass` is not visible at all in other packages. In above example, the import statement and the variable declaration fail too. It still might be a solution for your special case.

Comment: This is just what i needed. As you said, maybe i will have problems in the future due to lack of visibility, probably in test cases i believe, but for that i can always use reflection to get class reference. Thanks!