# Avoid a class to be extend anonymously in Java

Tags: java

In Java, is it possible to prevent a class for being extended anonymously?

For example

```
public class A () {
    public void hello() {}
}
```

I want to allow a named class extension:

```
public class B extends A {
}
```

but not anonymously:

```
A a = new A() {
    public void hello() {
    }
}
```

This is for serialization purpose.

Comment: No, there's no way to prevent anonymous subclassing specifically. If you really want to solve this without resorting to "subclasses must be easy to serialize" convention in your code base, I would suggest making the constructor of `A` package private (create a public factory method if you need to), and try to design it so that `B` lives in the same package.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider updating your question and explain your real problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to prevent creation of anonymous (inner) classes, but allow inheritance of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564238/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-creation-of-anonymous-inner-classes-but-allow-inher)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to accomplish this, through the use of a runtime exception:

```
class MyData implements Serializable {

    public MyData() {
        if (getClass().isAnonymousClass()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Anonymous subclasses are not serializable.");
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, anonymous classes are serializable, but it might be a good idea taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465641/serialization-of-anonymous-class-in-java) before trying to live with that.